# Rotate Sprite with AnalogController

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, 2d-games, google-play-games

Hello I am developing a game using andengine and now I want my sprite to be rotated with an OnScreenAnalogController. I've initialized it but now I can't figure out how to do the rest of the job. Any examples code or anything would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S Rotation should be around sprite's axis. And when I let go the controller I want the sprite to be facing in the direction where it has rotated not the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

For sprite rotations we override the applyRotation() method ->

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(0, 0, textureRegionForMySprite, getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
    @Override
    protected void applyRotation(GLState pGLState) {
        pGLState.rotateModelViewGLMatrixf(this.mRotation, 0, 1, 0);
    }
};
```

Comment: how do I implement this with the analogController I don't quite understand.

Comment: should I just do this and then add EntityModifer on the onControlChange on the AnalogOnScreenController? I think I'll try that but more detailed explanation would be great. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I kinda found a solution using this code

```
    mAnalogController = new AnalogOnScreenControl(90, cameraHeight - 130, mCamera, mControllerTextureRegion, mKnobTextureRegion, 0.01f, getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new IAnalogOnScreenControlListener(){

        @Override
        public void onControlChange(
                BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, float pValueX,
                float pValueY) {

            //rect.registerEntityModifier(new RotationByModifier(0.5f, MathUtils.radToDeg((float) Math.atan2(-pValueX, pValueY))));

            rect.registerEntityModifier(new RotationModifier(0.1f, rect.getRotation(), MathUtils.radToDeg((float) Math.atan2(pValueX, -pValueY))));
        }

        @Override
        public void onControlClick(
                AnalogOnScreenControl pAnalogOnScreenControl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

the only thing is when I release the controller it get's back to the initial position and rotating which is not what I want. Any ideas on how I can do that?